# Jaeger Tracing not working with yaml-cpp version 0.6.x

Tags: yaml-cpp, jaeger

I am trying to instrument my program with jaeger-tracing (c++).

I was able to view my traces when I compliled the program with yaml-cpp version 0.5.3, but when I changed my yaml-cpp version to 0.6.x, I am unable to view my traces.
Dont know why its happening.

JaegerProgram Source code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include<memory>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include<jaegertracing/Tracer.h>
#include<chrono>

using namespace std;
// using namespace literals::chrono_literals;

void init(const char *FilePath)
{
    auto yaml = YAML::LoadFile(FilePath);
    auto config = jaegertracing::Config::parse(yaml);
    auto tracer=jaegertracing::Tracer::make(
        "example-service-2",
        config,
        jaegertracing::logging::consoleLogger()
    );
    opentracing::Tracer::InitGlobal(
        static_pointer_cast<opentracing::Tracer>(tracer)
    );
}

void ChildSpan(const unique_ptr<opentracing::Span>& parentSpan){
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2));
    auto childSpan = opentracing::Tracer::Global()->StartSpan("Span2",{opentracing::ChildOf(&parentSpan->context())});
}

void FollowsSpan(const unique_ptr<opentracing::Span>& followFromspan){
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(3));
    auto followSpan = opentracing::Tracer::Global()->StartSpan("Span3",{opentracing::FollowsFrom(&followFromspan->context())});
}

void ParentSpan(){
    auto span = opentracing::Tracer::Global()->StartSpan("Span1");
    ChildSpan(span);
    FollowsSpan(span);
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(4));
}

int main()
{
    init("./config.yaml");
    ParentSpan();
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
    opentracing::Tracer::Global()->Close();
    return 0;
}
```

compiling command - `g++ -std=c++1z test.cpp -L /usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.a -ljaegertracing -lyaml-cpp`

Yaml file

```
disabled: false
reporter:
    logSpans: true
sampler:
  type: const
  param: 1
```

OS : ubuntu 18.04
jaegerTracing : master branch version

UPDATE

after little digging I found some fact, When I parse the above mention config file try to print the result I get the same value as written in config file, but when I parse same file using `yaml-cpp-0.6.x` the sampler.type is showing 'remote' and sampler.param to be '0.001' and when I manually change this change these values to be same as in `config.yaml` it has started showing traces. The error is present in parsing the yaml file as I could clearly see different values is loaded as configuration.

Comment: Can you try to reduce this to a minimal example? It's not clear what part of your code isn't working like you expect.

Comment: For example, can your figure out if the problem is in the YAML parsing or loading the Jaeger config? Perhaps try an example that doesn't use YAML at all and see if that works. Or just verify that the config you get is what you expect, without trying to create a Jaeger trace.

Comment: I dont think if there is any other way to load the configuration of Jaeger except for this one.

Comment: @JesseBeder I after little digging I found some fact, When I parse the above mention config file try to print the result I get the same value as written in config file, but when I parse same file using yaml-cpp-0.6.x the sampler.type is showing 'remote' and sampler.param to be '0.001' and when I manually change this change these values to be same as in config.yaml it has started showing traces. The error is present in parsing the yaml file

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Jaeger? Perhaps file a bug with them?

Comment: @JesseBederI dont think jaeger is working fine, but different verison of `yaml-cpp` is giving different result..also one more thing in version `0.6.x` the log spans is set to false permanantly no checking is done whether the log field is provided in `.yaml` file it is straightway initialized to false.